# My iPhone app crashes after opening it from background and selecting Tab atIndex:0

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, backgrounding

I really can't figure this out. When I click a link to open Safari from within my app, browse through the webpage, then return to my app, I can open and browse two `tabBarItems` in my `UITabBar`. But, when I try to select the one `atIndex: 0`, I get an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` and the following :(. Can anyone help me figure out how to make this not happen? I currently don't have any code that executes in `will` or `didEnterBackground` or `Foreground`. None. So the problem must be in the `UIViewController` for the first tab. (Oh and I don't know why it's adding a subview. Related?). Thoughts?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
        0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0109ba63 objc_msgSend + 23
        1   UIKit                           0x0031f3df -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 966
        2   UIKit                           0x0031f1b0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 407
        3   UIKit                           0x0031f1b0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 407
        4   UIKit                           0x0031f1b0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 407
        5   UIKit                           0x0031f1b0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 407
        6   UIKit                           0x0031f1b0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 407
        7   UIKit                           0x0031dfc4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 166
        8   UIKit                           0x00316dfc -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1080
        9   UIKit                           0x0031514f -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 57
        10  UIKit                           0x003725ac -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 563
        11  UIKit                           0x00371955 -[UITransitionView transition:toView:] + 129
        12  UIKit                           0x003a6383 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 459
        13  UIKit                           0x003a4d86 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
        14  UIKit                           0x003a6b7e -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 263
        15  UIKit                           0x003a69ed -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 352`
```

Comment: does it call viewDidLoad in your crashing view controller when the app returns back from bg?

Comment: Yep. And two of the three tabs are fine. But I think @rcw3 is correct. It's a memory issue for sure (I have a 1030 x 450 px image loaded that I haven't touched in terms of memory yet). What's the best way to deal with it? Should I reinit the image once it loads again? Or every time ViewDidLoad? I'm struggling with that since it's the cause of this BAD_ACCESS. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BAD_ACCESS means you are likely accessing something that points to memory that has been released.  In the situation you describe, it's very possible that your views are unloading due to a low memory warning - particularly ones that aren't visible.  If you aren't prepared for this unloading, when the view reloads, bad things usually happen.  Make sure you are appropriately handling your viewDidUnload method and the reciprocal viewDidLoad in your view controllers.

Comment: Including your code for these two methods would help. We could narrow down the issue even more.

Comment: Perfect. That has to be the issue. See my comment above. Do you have any ideas to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Figured it out. All I had to do was use the app delegate to reset the original context and nil the viewcontroller.