# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS iOS crash

Tags: ios, crash, exc-bad-access, kern-invalid-address

I am getting below crash logs across all iOS versions. However, I am not able to figure out the exact cause of this. Is it something to do with accessing a de-allocated object? If yes, is there a way to replicate the scenario since I am not able to.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180771b90 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreGraphics                   0x182574568 CGColorRetain + 28
2  CoreGraphics                   0x182609088 CGGStateSetStrokeColor + 64
3  UIKit                          0x186893698 -[UIKBHandwritingStrokeView drawRect:] + 692
4  UIKit                          0x1862e2678 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 368
5  QuartzCore                     0x183c16228 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 260
6  QuartzCore                     0x183c008ac CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2432
7  QuartzCore                     0x183d18360 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 52
8  QuartzCore                     0x183bffa88 CA::Layer::display_() + 1368
9  QuartzCore                     0x183be17a8 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 228
10 QuartzCore                     0x183be1494 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 44
11 QuartzCore                     0x183be0ab8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
12 QuartzCore                     0x183be0818 CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
13 UIKit                          0x186256ff4 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 4980
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1810b109c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1810b0b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1810ae830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
17 CoreFoundation                 0x180fd8c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
18 GraphicsServices               0x1828c0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
19 UIKit                          0x1862c2088 UIApplicationMain + 204
20 Smartphone                  0x1000e0b78 main (main.m:13)
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x180b768b8 (Missing)
```

Also I am not able to figure out where exactly the crash is happening. Since I am getting these as part of release build.

Comment: You can have a look on this, may be it could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958840/apple-rejected-my-app-due-to-crash-cant-reproduce-it

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user1416564 not yet. Tried a few things but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: @VijayBaswana unfortunately no. I'm looking at the exact same issue.

Comment: @VijayBaswana any luck? Are you using any particular libraries?

Comment: @user1416564 Not yer. However, one of my friends suggested that it could be due to some third party keyboards some users might be available using. But I couldn’t find any definite proof and hence never tried this. Please let me know if you find any fix for this. Thanks.